# accept() in message queues IPC UNIX

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, ipc

```
for (;;)
{
    if (msgrcv(msqid, &flag, sizeof(struct flags) - sizeof(long), 1, IPC_NOWAIT)>0)
           break;
}
    msgsnd(msqid, &message , sizeof(struct messages) - sizeof(long), 0);
```

Is there any `accept()` function like in `sockets` IPC, but for `message queues` IPC?
My server should wait client connection and only when client connected send data back to it.
I special send from client some useless data and check data in infinity loop(that means client is connected, I know that is very stupid algorithm).

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html - Read this network tutorial to understand basics of networking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing directly analogous.  Message queues are more like connectionless datagram sockets than they are like connection-oriented stream sockets (which support `accept()` and so forth).

Some implementations (z/OS?) expose the number of processes blocked on a `msgrcv`, which is similar to what you are looking for, but this is not portable.

As I see it, you have two easy options.

First, do what you are doing but don't IPC_NOWAIT in the server's `msgrcv`.  No point in spinning in a loop if you're not doing anything.  Just block until a client announces itself.  (And use different *message types* for communication from client-to-server and server-to-client — you don't want the clients consuming their messages to the server, nor vice-versa.)

Second, switch to AF_UNIX stream sockets, which will give you `accept()`able semantics.